# Tools / techniques to deal with complex HTML. Match Tags, comment tags etc

Tags: html

I've inherited a website with bad indenting and classic asp embedded in the pages.

It's difficult to work out the div structure of the pages. I use Ultraedit with code folding for matching tags but the embedded script can break it.

Are there any tools that will :

- nicely auto indent the pages
- comment html div tags eg.   and then  at the closing tag.

Any tips for editing complex html documents appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which operating system do you use?

In Linux, many editors from kate, gedit to vi, emacs supports your needs. Also there are various programs like [Quanta](http://www.osalt.com/quanta), [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) and [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) to edit HTML files. Aptana is really talented.

In windows, you can also use notepad++ . vi's GUI version [GVIM](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) is also available in windows.

You can also check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors for a comprehensive list of editors with comparison.